# Creating global settimeout variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am using a combination of jQuery and vanilla JavaScript for a slider I am working on. I'd probably try and put this into a single jQuery plugin but I lack knowledge of jQuery plugins and have yet to learn them.

The problem I have run into is that it seems my settimeout variable is not global across the jQuery and vanilla functions.

This is a problem because I need to be able to clear the timeout in certain situations. Example: when a user clicks a navigation button or arrow it should clear the current timeout and start it over.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* slider */

    if ($('.slider').length)
    {
        // setttings
        $caption_speed = 500;
        $slide_speed = 5000;

        // get slider height (px)
        $height = $('.slider .slides').outerHeight();

        // set top of all captions to slider height so they can be animated upwards
        $('.slider .slides li .caption').css('top', $height+'px');

        // get total slides
        $slides = $('.slider .slides li').length - 1;
        $active = 0;

        // show first slide caption
        captionActive($active, $caption_speed);
        $timeout = setTimeout(function () { nextSlide('right', $slides, $height, $caption_speed, $slide_speed, 'null'); }, $slide_speed);

        // pause slider if person mouses over caption, arrows, or nav
        $('.slider .slides li .caption, .slider .slide-arrows li, .slider .slide-nav').mouseover(function () {
            clearTimeout($timeout);
        });
        $('.slider .slides li .caption, .slider .slide-arrows li, .slider .slide-nav').mouseout(function () {
            $timeout = setTimeout(function () { nextSlide('right', $slides, $height, $caption_speed, $slide_speed, 'null'); }, $slide_speed);
        });

        // do arrow actions when clicked
        $('.slide-arrows li').click(function () {
            $direction = $(this).attr('class');
            nextSlide($direction, $slides, $height, $caption_speed, $slide_speed, 'null');
        });

        // do nav actions when clicked
        $('.slider .slide-nav li').click(function () {
            $number = $(this).index();
            nextSlide('right', $slides, $height, $caption_speed, $slide_speed, $number);
        });
    }

});

function captionActive (active, caption_speed) 
{
    $caption = $('.slider .slides li:eq('+active+') .caption');
    $cheight = $caption.outerHeight();
    $top = ($height - $cheight) / 2;        
    $caption.animate({opacity: 1, top: $top}, caption_speed, function () {});
    $('.slider .slide-nav li:eq('+active+')').addClass('active');       
}

function nextSlide (direction, slides, height, caption_speed, slide_speed, next)
{
    clearTimeout($timeout);

    // get active slide #
    $active = $('.slider .slide-nav .active').index();
    $active_slide = $('.slider .slides li:eq('+($active)+')');
    $('.slider .slide-nav .active').removeClass('active');

    if (next != 'null')
        $next = next;
    else if (direction == 'left')       
        $next = $active - 1;
    else
        $next = $active + 1;

    // check if next exists, otherwise make first next
    if (!$('.slider .slides li:eq('+($next)+')').length)
        $next = 0;  

    $next_slide = $('.slider .slides li:eq('+($next)+')');
    $next_slide.css('z-index', '99');

    // fade out caption
    $caption = $('.slider .slides li:eq('+$active+') .caption');
    $caption.animate({opacity: 0, top: height}, caption_speed, function () {});
    $active_slide.animate({opacity: 0}, caption_speed, function () {
        $active_slide.css({'z-index' : '0', 'opacity' : '100'});
        $next_slide.css('z-index', '100');
        // fade in new caption & set nav element active
        captionActive($next, caption_speed);
        $timeout = setTimeout(function () { nextSlide('right', slides, height, caption_speed, slide_speed, 'null'); }, slide_speed);
    });
}
```

See the following line within the nextSlide function:

```
clearTimeout($timeout);
```

This doesn't seem to clear the timeout. The timeouts appear to be stacking when I click on `.slide-arrows li` or `.slider .slide-nav li`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$timeout` variable is certainly accessible globally--as are all of your variables--as there is no use of the `var` keyword anywhere in your code.  This means all of your variables are global.  (This is not a good practice, but not related to this question.)

It seems your issue is actually that in your `nextSlide` function, the `setTimeout` is not called until your `animate` completes.  If you call the function again before the `animate` completes, then there's nothing to cancel.  Then both animates will complete, creating two timeouts.

What you should do is call `clearTimeout` immediately before setting the timeout:

```
$active_slide.animate({opacity: 0}, caption_speed, function () {
    /* ... */

    if($timeout) clearTimeout($timeout);

    $timeout = setTimeout(function () { nextSlide('right', slides, height, caption_speed, slide_speed, 'null'); }, slide_speed);
});
```

This will ensure that the timeout is cleared before creating a new timeout.